# Who can I get to do this?

Tags: latex-misc

I am a Senior in High School and I would love to do my Senior Project on LaTeX, but I have a problem. Who can I get to be my mentor/expert? I only know one person who knows about this but he lives like 8 states away. Is there some other person (like maybe an editor for a local paper or something) that I can ask?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic for this Q&A, since it is not directly related to (La)TeX.

Comment: Off-topic, probably more suited for a http://chat.stackexchange.com/ discussion.

Comment: Well you start slowly with any kind of tutorial on the web and shoot a gazillion of questions here and we will help you

Comment: If you like, ask me directly. I often tutor when it comes to LaTeX. ziegenhagen <at> gmail dot com